# How can I determine that the center of the circle lies inside the arc?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms, circles, programming

Or lies on chord?
Is there any algorithm to determine it?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CEoS.png)

In the first case the center lies outside the arc. In the second it is conversely.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of information are you given? If you are given, for example, the angle subtended by the arc, then it's a matter of whether that angle is greater than $180^{\circ}$ or not.

Comment: I have coordinates of two points on circle and center. I'm trying to write the programm, and very preferably not use angles and length of circle. It create extra complicated (in my case) cycle for computing

Comment: Two points and a center determine two arcs. How do you decide which arc to choose?

Comment: You should go from P1 to P2 according the image example

Comment: So, going clockwise from P1 to P2?

Comment: Yes.
It seems i have an idea. give me 2 minutes

Comment: I can draw two circles with centers in P1 and P1 using radius R. The first point of intersection is the main center.
if the second point of intersection to the left and above of the first, so the first point(required main center) lies outside the arc. 
if right and below so  one lies inside.
what do you think?

Comment: That wouldn't work, since your approach doesn't take into account your choice of the arc going clockwise from P1 to P2. If you switch P1 and P2, then your arc goes the other way, but your circles are still the same.

Comment: Sorry, you should pose the problem more clearly. You are given two points $P_1,P_2$ and the radius (its length) of circle. In the construction the chord and bisector of two radii are perpendicular to each other.Two solutions, one on each side of chord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the points on the circle, and let $C$ be the center. We have that $C$ lies inside the region bounded by the chord $P_1P_2$ and the arc going clockwise from $P_1$ to $P_2$ if the angle of the arc is greater than $180^{\circ}$, outside if the angle is less than $180^{\circ}$, and on the chord if the angle is $180^{\circ}$.

Let $\vec{u} = P_1 - C$ and $\vec{v} = P_2-C$, and consider the cross product $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$. (This is easily calculable if coordinates are given.) If the clockwise arc from $P_1$ to $P_2$ has angle greater than $180^{\circ}$, then by the right hand rule we have that the sign of $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ is positive. Correspondingly, if the arc has angle less than $180^{\circ}$, then the sign is negative, while if the arc has angle exactly $180^{\circ}$, then the cross product is zero.

Comment: I think you got the signs backwards.

Comment: @amd we are taking the arc going clockwise, hence my choice of signs.

Comment: @amd although I did get the relation between the angle and the positioning of the center backwards. It's fixed now.

Comment: Oops. Missed that detail. Better fix my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C=(x_0,y_0)$ be the circle’s center. Examine the sign of $(x_2-x_0)(y_1-y_0)-(x_1-x_0)(y_2-y_0)$. This is basically the $z$-component of $(P_2-C)\times(P_1-c)$. (Since we’re going clockwise, which by convention is a negative angle, we take $P_2$ first to reverse the sign.) If it’s positive, then the center is outside of the segment; if negative, the center is inside. If it’s zero, you either have $P_1=P_2$, or the points are on opposite sides of a diameter.